# .WebIde90 on Mac

Tags: symfony, themes, phpstorm

I'm trying to install Laravel color theme from github but it appears that I don't have a `.WebIde90` in my `/Library/Preferences/` directory ... 
I found it on `/Users/Me/` and tried to copy/paste the laravel theme into the directory but PhpStorm doesn't recognize this theme.

So I tried to copy the folder into `/Library/Preferences/` but doesn't work either.

I'm running PhpStorm 9.0.2 on Mac OS.

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs Full path would be `/Users/USERNAME/Library/Preferences/...`

Comment: My god didn't know I was this dumb. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

1. On Mac the `.WebIde90` folder should have no leading dot in it -- but it's present on Windows/Linux.
2. Such folder would be located in `~/Library/Preferences/` (notice the leading `~` which means "current user's home".

Therefore **the final path** would be `/Users/USERNAME/Library/Preferences/WebIde90`.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs